# Why isn't main.css found?

Tags: html, css, external

NOTE: I'm using Jekyll

I was trying to link an external style sheet but it doesn't find the file (which is main.css)so I tried to check again its path and its name and it still didn't work. May I have your help please?

Here you can see an image of my folder and my code:
[image]

Comment: Looks OK to me. What's the exact error you get? Cleared your cache?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `type="text/css"` to your `<link>`:

`<link href="_layouts/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0):

Your folder structures seems that you are using [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) if yes! then you need to change folder name ***_layouts*** is reversed folder for layout in jekyll

Comment: Could you explain please?

Comment: Jekyll is static website generator. check on given above.